# German stemmer is not removing feminine suffixes "-in" and "-innen"

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stemming, snowball-stemmer

In German, every job has a feminine and a masculine version. The feminine one is derived from the masculine one by adding an "-in" suffix. In the plural form, this turns into "-innen".

Example:

```
      | English          | German
------+------------------+-----------------------
masc. | teacher  doctor  | Lehrer      Arzt
fem.  | teacher  doctor  | Lehrerin    Ärztin
masc. | teachers doctors | Lehrer      Ärzte
fem.  | teachers doctors | Lehrerinnen Ärztinnen
```

Currently, I'm using NLTK's `nltk.stem.snowball.GermanStemmer`. 
It returns these stems:

```
Lehrer      -> lehr      | Arzt      -> arzt
Lehrerin    -> lehrerin  | Ärztin    -> arztin
Lehrer      -> lehr      | Ärzte     -> arzt
Lehrerinnen -> lehrerinn | Ärztinnen -> arztinn
```

Is there a way to make this stemmer return the same stems for all four versions, feminine and masculine ones? Alternatively, is there any other stemmer doing that?

### Update

I ended up adding "-innen" and "-in" as the first entries in the step 1 suffix-tuple like so:

```
stemmer = GermanStemmer()
stemmer._GermanStemmer__step1_suffixes = ("innen", "in") + stemmer._GermanStemmer__step1_suffixes
```

This way all of the above words are stemmed to `lehr` and `arzt` respectively. Also, all other "job-forms" that I tried so far are stemmed correctly, meaning masculine and feminine forms have the same stem. Also, if the "job-form" is derived from a verb, like `Lehrer/in`, they have the same stem as the verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The German Snowball stemmer [follows a three step process](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/german/stemmer.html):

1. Remove `ern`, `em`, `er`, `en`, `es`, `e`, `s` suffixes
2. Remove `est`, `en`, `er`, `st` suffixes
3. Remove `isch`, `lich`, `heit`, `keit`, `end`, `ung`, `ig`, `ik` suffixes

Not knowing a lot about German grammar, it seems that `in` would belong to the same class as the step 3 suffixes (these are referred to as "derivational suffixes" in the NLTK source). It would seem that adding `in` to this list of suffixes should force the Snowball stemmer to remove it but there are two problems.

The first problem is that from your examples I see that `in` becomes `inn` when followed by `en`. This could be worked around by adding both `in` and `inn` to the list of step 3 suffixes, but that doesn't solve the second problem.

Looking at the [`GermanStemmer.stem()` source](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/stem/snowball.html), each step will only remove a single suffix. Thus, if there is more than one derivational suffix (i.e. `in` plus any of the suffixes listed above], only the one will be removed.

In such cases (and I don't know enough about German to know if this can actually happen), you'd need to manually edit `GermanStemmer.stem()` to add a fourth "`in` removal" step. This would also allow finer control in the case of plurals. But honestly, at that point it's probably better to just ad hoc remove `in` by wrapping your `GermanStemmer.stem()` call. For example:

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import GermanStemmer

def stem_german(word):
    plural = word.endswith("en") #for deciding if we are looking for "in" or "inn"
    stemmed_word = GermanStemmer().stem(word)

    feminine_suffix = "in" if not plural else "inn"
    if stemmed_word.endswith(feminine_suffix):
        stemmed_word = stemmed_word[:-len(feminine_suffix)]

    return stemmed_word
```

--Edit--

If you wanted to add `in` to one of the Snowball Stemmer steps, you can do so using:

```
#Using nltk.stem.snowball.SnowballStemmer
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("german")
stemmer.stemmer._GermanStemmer__step3_suffixes += ("in",) #add "in" to the step 3 suffixes

#Using nltk.stem.snowball.GermanStemmer
stemmer = GermanStemmer()
stemmer._GermanStemmer__step3_suffixes += ("in",)
```

Note the comma after `"in"`. This code will not work without it. You can also replace the `3` with whichever step you wish to modify. I'm not entirely sure why it's `_GermanStemmer__step3_suffixes` and not just `__step3_suffixes` but I've verified that this code works on Python 3.6.4 and NLTK 3.2.5.

I would **not** recommend this approach, though, as it will not properly deal with `innen`. Also, since each step removes a maximum of one suffix, it will not properly deal with words like `Lehrerinnen` which have `en`, `in`, and `er` (step 3 doesn't check for `er`). I think your best bet is to just copy and paste the entirety of `GermanStemmer` (found in the source code link above. Use `ctrl+f`) and add a step 2.5 to `stem()` that checks for and removes `in/inn`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't see a way how to pass additional suffixes to the stemmer. Do I have to copy and modify the source? Also, I think `-in` rather belongs to step 1 (not sure though). That way step 2 would still remove the masculine "job-suffix" `-er`, if there is any like in `Lehrerin`. Your algorithm is not doing this btw. It will do `Lehrerin -> lehrer`. Maybe stemming it again after `in` and `innen` are gone could fix this?

Comment: See my edit. I think your best bet is to copy and modify `GermanStemmer.stem()` to add a step 2.5.

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot. I actually ended up adding `("innen", "in")` at the **front** of **step 1** suffixes and it seems to work just perfectly. By adding it in the front, `en` will never be removed from `innen` because `innen` is processed first. I haven't discovered any errors yet. There may be some words that coincidentally end on `in` without being feminine, but they are rare and this issue occurs with all the other suffixes as well.

Comment: And it looks like snowball would remove `en` from words ending with it even if they aren't plural anyway